# The right context

Tags: java, android

I want to use this MediaPlayer method from a number of fragment layouts.

How do I parse the raw resource ?

```
public void playSound(Uri path) throws IOException{
    MediaPlayer player;
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(path.getPath(), path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm currently using this from my fragment to parse an mp3 file from the raw directory.

```
Btn_shou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Uri path = null;

                switch (tone.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
                {
                    case R.id.radioTone1:

                        path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.shou1);
                        try {
                            playSound(path);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                        }
                        break;
```

There's a problem with the 'path' variable. Android complains it cannot find the mp3 file.

I finally fixed this by :

1. Create my separate MediaPlayer class.

   ```
   package com.example.FragmentTabsTutorial;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.media.MediaPlayer;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class plaSnd {

   public void playSound(Uri path, Context context) throws IOException {

       MediaPlayer player;
       player = new MediaPlayer();
       try {

           player.setDataSource(context, path);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();  
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SecurityException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); 
       } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
   }
       player.prepare();
       player.start();

       player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.release();

           }
        });

   }
   ```

   }

2.) From my fragment I created an object to plaSnd() class:

```
 final plaSnd pla = new plaSnd();
```

3.) Created a variable to store context:

```
final Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

4.) Set my path variable according to which button is clicked then parse 'context' and 'path' to my playSound() method in 'plaSnd' class:

```
 Btn_o.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Uri path = null;

            switch (tone.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
            {
                case R.id.radioTone1:

                    path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.o1);

                    try {
                        pla.playSound(path, context);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }

                    break;
```

This has worked for me though I'm sure there's probably a better solution...

Comment: `R.raw.shou1` is an integer in `R.java` isn't it? If you use it as part of the path, it won't work. You should try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
```

with this:

```
// context should be any context, e.g. your activity or getApplicationContext()
player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.shou1);
```

Comment: Thank-you Piovezan. But that's not really what I'm looking for. I haven't stated the question well...  I have a number or buttons that when pressed need to play the associated mp3. So the mp3 file is parsed dynamically depending on which button is selected. I should probably say my MediPLayer class is created as just a normal Java class - no inflater or onCreate method.